# Disqus Commenting: Remove 'original-title' attribute

Tags: jquery, disqus

I am having a problem with rewriting the styles for the Disqus commenting platform. The issue arises from trying to remove the 'original-title' attribute, which appears on hover of the avatar image of the user. To get rid of the 'original-title' text, I have used this CSS:

```
.dsq-avatar[original-title] {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This works fine to remove the text, however, when you hover the avatar image, it now removes the image, which you can see: http://disqus.dottalent.co.uk/app/

I have tried JQuery methods also to remove, but none seem to work. These are the methods I have also tried:

```
$('.dsq-avatar a, .dsq-tt a').unbind('hover mouseenter mouseleave');
```

What appears to be happening is that a js file is loaded from Disqus, which I can remove as I have done all the other CSS files from Disqus, but the js file includes both the hover event and other crucial javascript, so removing it completely doesn't help me.

Any help would be gratefully received as I am going both grey and mental!

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of tough to debug it from here, but have you tried removing the `original-title` attribute?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".dsq-avatar").removeAttr("original-title");
});
```

This looks like it took away the hover of text, which is what you're looking for correct?

Comment: I have given that a try. But it still appears. Seems to be due to the js coming from Disqus over writing it. I have tried this method too, to execute after page load:`code`$(window).bind("load", function () {$(".dsq-avatar").removeAttr("original-title");});`code`